# Open a pop-up page in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-webbrowser

I open a link in this selenium webdriver script:

```
from selenium import webdriver

search = input("Enter URL Here : ")
min = int(input("Enter Wait Time : "))
driver = webdriver.Firefox("")
driver.get(search)
time.sleep(8)
driver.quit()
```

But i want to open the Link in a single page Pop-up,, not with my pages in firefor or Chrome.
is there any code to use it..

and how can i make this script works automatic " to open and open any link i give it"

Comment: Bit confusing, what do you mean exactly by `I want to open the Link in a single page Pop-up` ?

Comment: i mean i want the script to open the link i give it in a pop-up, not in a Tab in my browser "Chrome or firefox"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible at this point of time in Selenium webdriver.

See Selenium is for browser automation, what it mean is, that you can simulate chrome or firefox or there are 5 others  browsers. But you cannot run selenium script in console or prompt you get by doing :

```
search = input("Enter URL Here : ")
min = int(input("Enter Wait Time : "))
```